# Access or pass variables to a interceptor in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, interceptor

I am new to NestJS and have been looking at a couple of solutions but haven't found a way.
My API returns list of users, the users are either read from the cache if present or from the DB and based on this I need to set the headers.
I want the interceptor to handle this part.

My Controller

```
  @UseInterceptors(CacheOrServiceHeaderInterceptor)
  @Get('users')
  public async users(
      @Query('id') clinicianId: number,
      @Query('name') specialtyName: string,
  ){
    const setFlags: MetaFlags = {setCacheHeader: false, setServiceHeader: false};

    const data = await this.service.getUsers(id, name, setFlags);
    return data;
}
```

My service class

```
export interface MetaFlags {
  setServiceHeader: boolean
  setCacheHeader?: boolean,
}
:
:
public async getUsers(....){
// code that handles whether cache is used or a service is used to get users
 and based on it, the metaFlags are set. setCacheHeader = true if read from cache or setServiceHeader = true if read from DB.
```

My interceptor looks like this

```
@Injectable()
export class CacheOrServiceHeaderInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  
    public intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
       
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
                map((data) => {
                    const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    // this is static but I want a condition here if 
                    if(MetaFlags.setCacheHeader)
                    // set xyz header
                     else set abc header
                    req.res.set('x-api-key', 'pretty secure');
                    return data;
                }
                 
            )
        );}}
```

Is there a way to pass these flags to the interceptor or make the interceptor read these flag values ?

Comment: For the `setCacheHeader` and `setServiceHeader` are those values returned as part of the data from the service, or are you touching a global state for that?

Comment: I don't return it as part of the data from the service. I access the global state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest returning what header should be set as a part of the service of controller's return. If you end up using a global state, you could get multiple requests to the endpoint overwriting the global state before you read it in the interceptor and send back the wrong header. Something like

```js
{
  data: regularDataHere,
  header: 'cache' || 'database'
}
```

Now in the `map` of your interceptor, you can read the `data` object and pull off the `data` property to return only it and not expose this `header` field to the client, **and** read the `header` field so you know which header to set on the response. Something like this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CacheOrServiceHeaderInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  
    public intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handler().pipe(
      map((data: { data: DataType, header: 'cache' | 'database' }) => {
        const res = context.switchToHttp().getResponse<ResponseType>();
        if (data.header === 'database') {
          res.setHeader('x-api-key', 'pretty secure');
        } else {
          res.setHeader(xyz, value);
        }
        return data.data;
      })
    );
  }
}
```